# bulk sms gsm modem

Tags: gsm, modem, bulksms

I am doing a project for sending bulk sms service.this is the concept

create a website . Through this website the user will enter all their details so that only registered user can use my service.I ll get a service plan from any of the service providers for sending  unlimited messages.They ll give me a SIM card with a unique  number like 54545.My android  application interfaces with the gsm modem and sends out the messages from my machine.
now,i wanted to know what kind of modem i can use for my project.Is there any modem to send only bulk sms

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a GSM/GPRS-[Terminal](http://www.cinterion.com/products/terminals/tc65t.html) like these. I have used one to send SMS after a application has finished processing data or if an error occured.